# Display a count number in a Access Report into a Text Box on Access form

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to link and display a =Count([last Name]) from an access report into a Text Box which will display it on a form. Without having to open and close the report to see how many enteries are in there.
Any help would be much aporia coated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the same recordsource as the report with something like

```vb
=DCount("[last Name]","[myQuery]")
```

where `myQuery` is the queryname of the reports recordsource.